# SharePoint 2010 + Not able to update User Photo

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I got a  strange issue, like Even if I upload the user photo (From edit profile page), its not reflecting. Thats its still showing the older image. Can anybody help me in this ? Thanks in advance.